# Automatic clone, pull request and merge use GitHub Actions

Tags: shell, github-actions

I have 2 repositories.

When I make changes in the main repository, I want to clone change and make a pull request in the second repository automatically using GitHub action.

How would you implement such a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that that through a combination of GitHub Actions (hooks executed on the GitHub server side)

- on your repo1, you can associate on each push a [`actions/github-push`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-push) workflow, in order to push to repo2 whatever was pushed on repo1
- on your repo2, you can associate a [`vsoch/pull-request-action`](https://github.com/vsoch/pull-request-action) workflow:

> This action will open a pull request to master branch (or otherwise specified) whenever a branch with some prefix is pushed to.
> The idea is that you can set up some workflow that pushes content to branches of the repository, and you would then want this push reviewed for merge to master.